# Cocoa - Easiest way to convert the string 'employeeName' into 'Employee Name'?

Tags: cocoa, string

1. I have a string employeeName, what's the easiest way to change this to 'Employee Name' in cocoa?
2. Also how would I just extract the first word in the above?

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSScanner for the string, then tell it to [scan up until](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:) an [uppercase letter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/uppercaseLetterCharacterSet). If you want to scan more than one word, then scan one word at a time multiple times, until you run out of words.

I believe that NSScanner won't scan any further once you're *at* an uppercase letter, so you'll need to [scan the uppercase letter(s) into one string](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:), then scan everything up to the next run of them into another string, then join those two strings.